# Refresh panel in Wicket with BootstrapDownloadLink

Tags: java, wicket

My problem is simple but I have no clue how to solve it. I have a `feedbackPanel` and I want to show an error message if the `BootstrapDownloadLink` fails. With a submit I could easily do:

```
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    ...
    error("File_not_found");  //Wicket will print this on the feedback panel
    target.add(getModalPanel().getFeedbackPanel()); //But i need to refresh it first
}
```

But the button is inside a panel which I fill with a populateItem and is the only way I know to insert Bootstrap Styles to it. The code of the button:

```
BootstrapDownloadLink downloadDocument = new BootstrapDownloadLink(IDITEMREPEATER, file) {                                  

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        File file = (File)getModelObject();
        if(file.exists()) {
            IResourceStream resourceStream = new FileResourceStream(new org.apache.wicket.util.file.File(file));
            getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(resourceStream, file.getName()));
        } else {
            error(getString("error_fichero_no_existe"));
            /// ???? need to refresh-> getModalPanel().getFeedbackPanel()
        }
    }


};
downloadDocument.setIconType(GlyphIconType.clouddownload);
downloadDocument.add(new AttributeModifier("title", getString("documentos.descargar")));
downloadDocument.add(new AttributeModifier("class", " btn btn-info negrita btn-xs center-block"));
downloadDocument.setVisible(Boolean.TRUE);
list.add(downloadDocument);
```

Comment: What is `BootstrapDownloadLink`? It is not part of wicket-core?

Comment: Yes, it isn't. I forget about that, sorry. Is a class that extends from **DownloadLink** and Implements **IBootstrapButton**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create or extend from an `AjaxDownloadLink`, for example like [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=webanno/webanno/webanno-master/webanno-support/src/main/java/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/clarin/webanno/support/wicket/AjaxDownloadLink.java).

The main idea is to have an `AjaxBehavior` that does the download, and you get a `public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)` in which you can add the `FeedbackPanel`

```
 downloadBehavior = new AbstractAjaxBehavior()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 3472918725573624819L;

            @Override
            public void onRequest()
            {
                [...]                   
                ResourceStreamRequestHandler handler = new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(
                        AjaxDownloadLink.this.getModelObject(), name);
                handler.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.ATTACHMENT);
                getComponent().getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(handler);
            }
        };
```

And use that behavior in the onclick:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget aTarget)
    {
        String url = downloadBehavior.getCallbackUrl().toString();

        if (addAntiCache) {
            url = url + (url.contains("?") ? "&" : "?");
            url = url + "antiCache=" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        // the timeout is needed to let Wicket release the channel
        aTarget.appendJavaScript("setTimeout(\"window.location.href='" + url + "'\", 100);");
    }
```

Comment: Yes! I was testing it and that worked just fine. And even better, I can use this solution for other problems I had. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `target.addChildren(getPage(), IFeedback.class)`. This will add **all** instances of IFeedback interface in the page to the AjaxRequestTarget.

You can also use `FeedbackPanel.class` instead of the interface.

Or use `getPage().visit(new IVisitor() {...})` to find a specific feedback panel if you don't want to add others which are not related.

Comment: I think the problem is that his `DownloadLink` does not have a `target` in the onclick, as it is not a `AjaxLink` ?